# redirect created files in a directory from command line

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, io-redirection, netcat

I was wondering if there is any way to redirect created files from a .sh script to a specific directory **without** modifying the script itself but straight from command line.

Let's say:

I've a script *prove.sh* that creates some file in the current directory:

`cat prove.sh`

---

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "try 1" > try.1.txt

echo "try 2" > try.2.txt
```

---

and I would like to redirect those created files **not** in the current directory but in another directory (let's say ~/Documents/prove/) straight from my:

`sh prove.sh <...something to redirect files to directory...>`

**without** modifying the script itself.

Do you think is it possible?

Anyone has got a clue?

EDITED: More specifically, what I need to do is to redirect the output of a program that runs on a server and that creates various file (not stdout nothing) in a specified directory in the *--out* field, to another computer **directly** (without writing anything in the original server where the program runs).

I've only host access to this server so I can not install or sudo anything. Listening a port in the second server and redirect the output to this port in nectat did not work due to firewall in the server where the program runs that I cannot change.

Some idea?

Comment: What do you mean by _in a specified directory in the --out field_? Your added "EDITED" bit changes the original question quite a bit. Could you maybe combine the two so that it reads as a single uniform question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the script looks exactly like what you have shown:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "try 1" > try.1.txt
echo "try 2" > try.2.txt
```

The files would be created in the current directory, regardless of what the current directory was.

Therefore, to create the files in `~/Documents/prove/`, you would be able to do

```
( cd ~/Documents/prove/ && bash /some/location/prove.sh )
```

where `/some/location/prove.sh` is the pathname of the script itself.

This would `cd` to the given directory first, and if that went well (the directory exists and you have permission to be there) then `bash` would be invoked to run the script and the files would be created there, assuming you had permissions to create files in that directory.

I put the commands within `( ... )`, a subshell, so that the `cd` would not affect the original working directory.  This means that you should find yourself in the same directory where you started after executing that line.

Without the `( ... )`, you would have changed directory to `~/Documents/prove/`.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, but I was wondering if there is a way to call the script BEFORE and then redirect it (because I need to pipe in SSH so I have to call the script before CD)

Comment: @ccc.nrc There is absolutely nothing preventing you from running both a `cd` and the script in the same `ssh` call. Please update your question with the requirements that you have.